# Question about Lyapunov functions and its application on stability - Particular Example

Tags: systems-of-equations, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

So, basically I am given the following exercise:

**Exercise.** Study de following system null solution stability with the Lyapunov function method.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
x' = x^3-y \\[5pt]
y' = x+y^3
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Suggestion: Consider $V(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$.

**My resolution.** To check if $V$ is indeed a Lyapunov function, I do the following:
\begin{equation*}
V \in C^1 \quad\text{in $\mathbb{R^2}$} \\[5pt]
V(0,0) = 0 \\[5pt]
V(x,y) > 0, \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}\backslash\{(0,0)\}
\end{equation*}
And the last condition is where the problem comes. In this case, take $f(x,y) = (x^3-y,x+y^3)$. Thus, it urges the following:
\begin{equation*}
f_1(x,y)\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}(x,y) + f_2(x,y)\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}(x,y) = 2(x^4+y^4) \geq 0
\end{equation*}
So, $V$ doesnt' satisfy the conditions to be a Lyapunov function. (the last equation sould be $\leq 0$). I don't see where I am making a mistake here? Is the exercise wrong? (by this I mean the suggestion I am given).

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have shown is that any trajectory $(x(t),y(t))$ (except the constant solution $(x,y)=(0,0)$) increases its distance from the origin as $t$ increases. So the origin is an unstable equilibrium.

Comment: Thanks Hans! So, in a general case, if I have that $f_1(x,y)\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}(x,y) + f_2(x,y)\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}(x,y) \geq 0$, i.e., (positive defined) I can conlude that the  origin  is unstable?

Comment: Yes, except that the correct terminology is positive *definite*, and that this means that the equality is *strict* in a punctured neighbourhood of the equilibrium: $\dot V > 0$. In fact, in this case you don't need $V$ itself to be positive definite, it's enough that it doesn't have a local maximum at the origin.

Comment: @rpd The name of theorem that doesn't require a positive definite $V$ that Hans is referring to is called Chetaev instability theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the information!